# Impyla not using configuration parameters

Tags: python, hive, impala

I'm trying to use `impyla` to connect to a Hive 0.14 server using Tez:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.utils import to_pandas
connection = connect(host='myhost', port=10000, auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
cursor = connection.cursor(configuration={'job.queue.name':'myqueue'})
cursor.execute('show databases') # works ok
cursor.fetchall() # works ok
cursor.execute('select field1, field2 from mydb.mytable where field1 > 2015') # breaks!
df = to_pandas(cursor) # never gets here
```

Error:

```
HiveServer2Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

What is going on? It seems that `configuration` is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Impyla implements the [Python database API](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). Looking at the docs, it looks like the `cursor()` method doesn't take any arguments. `execute()`, however, [takes a `configuration` kwarg](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/blob/46087826f1bc0ec09ac590795cfb45d7121315ba/impala/interface.py#L114). Try:

```py
cursor.execute('select field1, field2 from mydb.mytable where field1 > 2015', configuration={'job.queue.name':'myqueue'})
```